Fast loading of a large interface made with pyside6-designer
I have created a large and complex application interface through pyside6-designer. I got a .ui file with more than 15,000 lines. When converting through pyside6-uic I get a single .py file where all widgets are set in a single “setupUi” function.
Problem: When calling "setupUi" function in my code, my application freezes for 1-2 sec.
Questions: Is there an alternative to pyside6-uic in the pyside6 ecosystem that would use lazy loading? Maybe I am missing some parameters when using pyside6-uic? What approach do you recommend to quickly load complex interfaces made via pyside6-designer?
Dividing a .ui file into smaller ones is highly undesirable. In the future I would like to edit the whole interface in pyside6-designer at once.

Even with one of the largest UI I've ever made (having more than 1000 widgets), I didn't get more than 4000 lines. It seems rather odd that you have such a huge file, unless it contains lots of long text based properties, including stylesheets, or you use high level item views (eg: QTreeWidget). Can add a screenshot of the UI and a brief summary of its structure?
